# Xamarin Forms: How notify my previous viewmodel than is observable collection need to be modified?

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I use an observable collection with a selecteditem (name + detail) to push a new contentpage in my navigation and in this new page i modify the name of this selected item but in an other list.

I would like to refresh the data in the observable collection with this other list (saved in an internal storage)

So, can i use an event to notify the previous viewmodel than i push the back button and if it possible which event can i use?

Answer (score 0):

**[Xamarin.Forms.Page](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Page/#Public_Events)**

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     When overridden, allows application developers to customize behavior immediately
    //     prior to the Xamarin.Forms.Page becoming visible.
    //
    // Remarks:
    //     To be added.
    protected virtual void OnAppearing();
```

This may be helpfull you'll need to override it in your page code.

Answer (score 0):

Overriding the `OnAppearing` method seems the simplest way to achieve this. This way you'll keep the logic to refresh the data in the page that belongs with the viewmodel that needs to be refreshed. When the page re-appears, it can trigger some logic in the ViewModel to refresh the `ObservableCollection`.

Another option is to use the `MessagingCenter` that comes with Xamarin.Forms: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/messaging-center/ This allows pub/sub style messaging between components while staying loosely coupled. You could have the class that manages the internal storage publish messages whenever the list in the gets updated and broadcast this to ViewModels that have subscribed to these updates.

In this particular case, overriding `OnAppearing` seems the simplest solution though.